# jquery fade doesn't seem to work

Tags: jquery, asp.net, fade

I'm trying to add a div that fades in/out when i press a button. this is the code in my ASP head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(this.document).ready(function () {
      $("#<%=this.button1.ClientID %>").click(function () {
         $("#mydiv").fadeToggle();
      });
   });
</script>
```

and then this later down in body:

```
<asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" Text="button" />

<div id="mydiv" style="display:none">
Load page with fade in effect...<br />
Load page with fade in effect...<br />
Load page with fade in effect...<br />
Load page with fade in effect...<br />
Load page with fade in effect...<br />
Load page with fade in effect...<br />
Load page with fade in effect...<br />
Load page with fade in effect...<br />
Load page with fade in effect...<br />
Load page with fade in effect...<br />
Load page with fade in effect...<br />
Load page with fade in effect...<br />
Load page with fade in effect...<br />
</div>
```

When I test it, the button is there but nothing happens when i press it. when i SPAM press it repetedly, i can see the div starting to fade in/out, but just flickering for a milliseccond.

Comment: is this the only javascript you have in the page ? It seems correct at first sight so maybe another part of the script is interfering ?

Comment: Yea, this is the only javascript I have. I used '$(document).ready' but changed that for testing purposes. It didn't work then either. Yes, the ID is the same (I've checked 100 times ^^ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the button is always make post back, so you did not see the javascript running because your page is reloaded.

You can use the `return false;` or the [`preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) to avoid the post back and see your client side effect.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(this.document).ready(function () {
      $("#<%=this.button1.ClientID %>").click(function (event) {
         // not let it make post back
         event.preventDefault();

         $("#mydiv").fadeToggle();
      });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks alot! I would never have figured that one out myself ^^'

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$("selector").fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
```

it will fade with slow effect

Comment: doesn't help much. It's still only visible for like 0.25sec before it vanishes again(not fadeout, just disapear instantly)

Answer (score 0):

Specify a duration for `.fadeToggle()`.  The default is 400, which is pretty quick.  `.fadeToggle(1000)` will take a second.